# Why boost asio signal handler is immediately canceled?

Tags: c++, boost, signals, boost-asio

I have the following code snippet:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void startAsyncWaitForSignal(boost::asio::io_service& ioService)
{
    boost::asio::signal_set signals{ioService};
    signals.add(SIGTERM);
    signals.async_wait(
        [&ioService](boost::system::error_code errorCode, int signalNumber)
        {
            std::cerr << errorCode.message() << std::endl;
            if (!errorCode) {
                std::cerr << "received signal " <<  signalNumber << std::endl;
                startAsyncWaitForSignal(ioService);
            }
        }
    );
}

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service ioService;
    startAsyncWaitForSignal(ioService);
    ioService.run();
}
```

I'd expect this program to wait, until the first SIGTERM is arrived, then wait to the next, then again to the next, ...

However the program is immediately terminates with the following output:

```
Operation canceled
```

What is the reason of this immediate operation cancel? I tried to make an io_service::work object, but that just changed the fact that ioService.run() was not finished, but the signal_set was still canceled immediately.

I am using boost 1.54. There is a [bug fix related to asio/signals in 1.55](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/8738), but that looks like a different issue.

Comment: When leaving `startAsyncWaitForSignal()` the local `signal_set` variable gets destroyed and the `async_wait` call gets cancelled. The `signal_set` needs to live just a little longer...

Comment: If you make this as answer I will accept this. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When leaving `startAsyncWaitForSignal()` the local `signal_set` variable gets destroyed and the `async_wait()` call gets cancelled. The `signal_set` needs to live just a little longer. Move it out of `startAsyncWaitForSignal()` and pass it as a parameter, for example:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void startAsyncWaitForSignal(boost::asio::io_service& ioService, boost::asio::signal_set& signals)
{
    signals.async_wait(
        [&ioService, &signals](boost::system::error_code errorCode, int signalNumber)
        {
            std::cerr << errorCode.message() << std::endl;
            if (!errorCode) {
                std::cerr << "received signal " <<  signalNumber << std::endl;
                startAsyncWaitForSignal(ioService, signals);
            }
        }
    );
}

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service ioService;
    boost::asio::signal_set signals{ioService};
    signals.add(SIGTERM);
    startAsyncWaitForSignal(ioService, signals);
    ioService.run();
}
```

Comment: nice A but "just a bit longer" is kid of a pointless measurement?

Comment: the `signal_set` needs to remain in scope for the entire duration of the `async_wait` call.

Comment: @SamMiller I think that's not 100% correctly expressed (I know that you know what you mean!). In the original code sample the scope of `signal_set` is just that: the entire duration of `async_wait`. But the scope needs to be even wider: as long as the wait handler has not been called.

Comment: I think that the problem of the original code is that the lambda makes it look like as if the current execution scope stays in startAsyncWaitForSignal while practically it immediatly returns and the lambda is called later from inside `ioService.run()`.

Comment: @Matthias247 Full ACK!